# ubuntu18.04 boot failed because of not exit 0 in /etc/rc.local file

Tags: boot, 18.04, systemd

ubuntu18.04 boot failed because of not go `exit 0` in /etc/rc.local file
It just stay on the boot page, and can't in system.

```
#!/bin/bash
# do something just like echo log to file
exit 0
```

I'am sure the /etc/rc.local file run, and get some error.
How can I fix this problem.

Comment: Can you include the contents of `/etc/rc.local` in your question? Also include the results from `systemctl status rc.local`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /etc/rc.local files on Ubuntu and Debian systems are used to execute commands at system startup.

So let's Create the /etc/rc.local file with your fav text editor.

```
vim /etc/rc.local
```

copy and paste the below.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0
```

save and exit

Now make it executable.

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

That's it. You can now use this file to execute commands at system boot.

Just paste your commands above the line that says exit 0